# Validate Text Response using restAssured

Tags: rest-assured

How to validate Text Response using restAssured?
Basically I have downloaded the file In CSV format, now the response is coming in text format any suggestion how can we validate the column headers in the text?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer.

```
    try {
        CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
        File file = new File(fileName) ;
        MappingIterator<T> readValues = mapper.readerFor(type).with(bootstrapSchema).readValues(file);
        return readValues.readAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occurred while loading object list from file :{} with }
```

using Jackson csv formatter dependency